# Remove padding in Qt

Tags: user-interface, qt5, pyqt5

I try to reduce padding around nested widgets in Qt in python (used by pyqt5 library). I try:

1. `self.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)`
2. `layout.setSpacing(0)` - inner widgets are touching, but padding still exists

I would like to everything inside frame start in this same position like checkbox near "Synchronize views"
Everything inside border is custom class which derivative from QWidget.

[image: problem visualization]

Comment: Are you calling `setContentsMargins` on the layout as well as the widget?

Comment: No. I try this separately. Add in both places do job. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Apply this to all layouts, which create unwanted margins.